# How to run jhipster javascript test case

Tags: javascript, testing, tdd, jhipster

I generated web project by using jhipster, and I found there were some generated javascript code as well.

How could I run these javascript test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript tests can be performed by running the command `gulp test` in the root of the generated project.

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, you can create a Karma run/debug configuration. To do so, set up the generated `karma.conf.js` as the configuration file and choose `node_modules/karma` as the Karma package. This lets you take advantage of IntelliJ IDEA's testing features, such as automatic testing on changes and a nice test results screen.